# What does `;` and `&&` do to variable assignment expressions in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, environment

I am pretty confused about below experiment results here and want to understand it better:

1. ```
    root@localhost$ TEST=test env | grep test
    TEST=test
   ```
2. ```
    root@localhost$ TEST=test && echo ${TEST}
    test
    root@localhost$ TEST=test; echo ${TEST}
    test
   ```
3. ```
    root@localhost$ TEST=test && env | grep test
    root@localhost$ TEST=test; env | grep test
   ```
4. ```
    root@localhost$ TEST=test && TEST=${TEST} env | grep test
    TEST=test
    root@localhost$ TEST=test; TEST=${TEST} env | grep test
    TEST=test
   ```
5. ```
    root@localhost$ export TEST=test && TEST=${TEST} env | grep test; unset TEST
    TEST=test
    root@localhost$ export TEST=test; TEST=${TEST} env | grep test; unset TEST
    TEST=test
   ```

My main confusion being that:

Why does not #3 work?

Why does #4 work?

Comment: `;` is like a newline. `TEST=test; echo $TEST` is two lines of code. The first "line" is a variable assignment. The second line prints that variable

Comment: `&&` is also like a newline except the second line is executed if and only if the first line is successful. So it is like a newline combined with an `if` statement

Comment: The answer by @ikegami is pretty good. My recommendation is don't use `;`, `&&` or `||`. There's never any reason to replace a newline with `;`. And the `&&` and `||` operators create problems when used in any manner other than `a && b` or `a || b`. For example, what does `a && b || c` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of vars: Environment (exported) vars, and shell vars.

- `VAR=val` sets the env var named `VAR` if it already exists.
- `VAR=val` sets the shell var named `VAR` if env var `VAR` doesn't exist.
- `VAR=val cmd` sets the env var named `VAR` for `cmd` only.

The env vars are provided to child processes as their environment.

Shell vars, on the other hand, exist only within that shell process. Child processes have no access to them.

So,

1. You set env var `TEST` for the command.
2. You set shell var `TEST`.
3. You set shell var `TEST`.
4. You set shell var `TEST`. Then you set env var `TEST` for the command.
5. You env shell var `TEST`. Then you set env var `TEST` for the command.

> Why does #4 work?

You set an env var.

> Why does not #3 work?

You did not set any env vars.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @ikegami is very nice, and he highlighted differences between environment variables and shell variables. But I have something about bash how to split and execute these long commands to append.

For a long command, bash will regard it as some smaller command components, such as

- simple commands
- pipelines
- lists of commands

and so on, which you can look at [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Commands).

1. Simple commands

   Simple commands are most common, and a utility executable (maybe with arguments) is simple command, such as `env` and `grep test` in your examples. You can prepend some variable assignments before simple commands to [apply env vars temporarily just to it](https://temporarily), such as `TEST=test env`. Shell built-in command is simple command too, such as `export TEST=test`. There is no strict definition for simple commands, and I think variable assignments can be regarded as simple commands from the syntax’s point of view, but of course variables assignments before another simple command are not, they are temporary env vars.
2. Pipelines

   Pipelines are some commands connected using `|`, such as `TEST=test env | grep test`, which includes two simple commands.
3. Lists of commands

   Lists of commands is a sequence of **one or more pipelines** separated by operators, such as `&&`, `;`, and so on. `&&` means only when previous pipelines succeed would the latter pipelines get executed. `;` means all pipelines would get executed sequentially.

For example, both commands of #4 can be interpreted by bash as following tree (Abstract Syntax Tree):

```
                               list of commands
                         _____________|______________
                        |                            |
                    pipeline                      pipeline
                        |                      _______|_______
                        |                     |               |
                  simple command    simple command    simple command
                        |                 |                   |
                  TEST=test       TEST=${TEST} env         grep test
```

Bash will execute this tree from left subtrees and nodes to right subtrees and nodes. And be aware that `TEST=${TEST} env` is **one indivisible command unit**.